# ¿Porque mi consola se ve asi?

Tags: java, consola, intellij-idea

soy nuevo en esto y tengo una duda, para estudiar Java yo estaba usando el IDE eclipse, pero por el tema de interfaces gráficas me fui a NetBeans ya que el curso que estoy viendo lo hace ahí, bueno, el caso, al ejecutar mis programas la consola me muestra cosas las cuales no tengo ni idea de que son, y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de quitarlas porque es bastante molesto, dejo una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y también al terminar de ejecutar me salen otras cosas. No sé que es pero se que antes no me salía se me hace algo molesto, saben que es?

Se que no afecta en nada a la hora de programar y eso, pero antes no estaba y me surgió la duda.

Answer (score 1):

Es solo la manera en la que maven representa el output del programa en NetBeans. Es básicamente la descripción de lo que hace al ejecutar la aplicación pero hasta donde yo se no hay realmente una manera de quitarlo, a menos que uses Eclipse el cual no muestra eso ya que a pesar de que también integra Maven lo hace en la consola que pertenece directamente a Eclipse.